# Importing google-play-service library, appear "No projects are found to import"

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-maps, import

I tried importing google-play-service library, but it shows me the message below.

It's the Path:

[image: It's the Path]

IT's the message:

[image: This is the message]

What did I do wrong?!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hey,Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem**

Copy your google play service from eclipse and paste in same derive of your system where you create project, then check.

if it not work then create new workspace and check. sometime it make app by default and said there is no project.

Checkout and tell me if it work or not

Comment: it's not works, I'd try exactly you told me. Thanks you!

Comment: Works when I create new workspace and create a new project. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You just Import the project **Sdk/extras/google/google_play_sevices/libproject/google_play_services_ib/**
dont go beyond this path, just imort this whle projest.

Note: While importing or attaching lib project with your project then take care of one thing:
         If path appear on import starts with a drive letter(C:, D: etc) then ,it means import not successful, it should be start with dot (...)

The library project should be on same location where your project is (for successfull import.) while it is in workspace on at any other location.

Answer (score 0):

try to paste it in directly in your workspace and if you simply wants to add jar files then use buildpath option for particuler project.